My .htaccess file's redirect for URL query trails does not appear to work
Good day, I would like my site to direct trailing queries in the URL to a simple "/".
For example: "https://www.website.com/page?url_query=my-article" to "https://www.website.com/page/my-article", replacing "?url_query=" to "/"
I apologise if I have clearly overlooked something obvious. I have read through multiple StackOverflow articles on this topic, all with similar but slightly varied answers. None seem to work within my .htaccess file. Is there something in my file that is overriding/conflicting with the this code?
The link above is an example, in my exact URLs I have minimised "?url_query=" to just "?l=" so that while the trailing query is present, it is at least as minimum as it can be.
Here are the exact pages* I am working with:
https://localhost/clarity/i?l=my-event
https://localhost/clarity/library/event?l=my-event
https://localhost/clarity/library/article?l=my-article

*these are actually within "/htdocs/clarity/public/page.php", not "/htdocs/clarity/page.php".
.htaccess:
# Disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

# Rewrite URLs
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /clarity/

# Redirect to https and www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clarity\.rf\.gd [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.clarity.rf.gd/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect to public folder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]

# Replace "?l=" to "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?test/(.*?)/?$ /test.php?l=$1 [L]

# Redirect from "?l=" to "/"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /test\.php\?l=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?test\.php$ /test/%1? [L,R=301]

# Remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

# Remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Final clarification, everything else within my .htaccess file works as intended. The "https" and "www" redirects and the removal of the ".html", ".php" extensions.
~ Thank you for your time

To rewrite as you wish use the following text and duplicate it with the good argument each time i.e :

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url_query=my-article$
RewriteRule ^page$ https://www.website.com/page/my-article? [R=301,L]`

Or with automation

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url_query=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/url_query=$ $1?page=%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]`

R=301 : Type of redirection permanent means after SEO and all stuf you will "maybe" delete the old url. In any case the good url is this one ...
Have a good day...

Hi, please readformatting help
